# Using long `enum` list with hex values

Tags: c++, enums

Suppose I have an `enum` which has more than `64` entries, and I would like to assign hex values for easier bit-hacking comparisons, such as `(verify & (ENUM_ONE | ENUM_TWO))`. Since not even `unsigned long int` would be enough, is it considered bad practice if I use normal `enum` values (as in `ENUM_ZERO = 0`, `ENUM_ONE = 1`, etc) and then use `(verify & ((1<<ENUM_ONE) | (1<<ENUM_TWO)))`? As I understand it, bit shifting comes cheap, and it looks like I managed to avoid conditionals, but what about the code?

Comment: You will still have the problem that if you try to shift by too many bits, whatever integer type you are using to represent those bits will overflow.

Comment: I don't see how this gains you any extra bits.

Comment: You are both right, I completely missed that. Is there a workaround for this? I have a ton of checks plus a monster `switch/case` function that stabs me in the retina everytime aI look at it.

Comment: Next step might be to use a `std::bitset`, which can hold more than 64 bits. Or ask yourself if having more than 64 independent parameters to the code really is such a great idea.

Comment: Sounds to me like you may want to reconsider your design.

Comment: @BoPersson Well, it's a long list, and it's actually paired with a `std::string` inside a `struct`, used for functions (the `enum`) and `QComboBox`es. And they're more thatn one. At this point, I could split the `enum` (and `struct`&co) into something like `Enum1`, `Enum2`, etc, it would work, but I don't think it would look pretty...